# Access variable from java class from build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, annotations, build.gradle

I am trying to annotate a class in java with a version supplied from a build.gradle but I got the error that the value has to be constant, so now I am trying the other way around. If I set a static final string in a java class, can I access it from the build.gradle to use as my version attribute?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-gradle-variables-in-my-java-method/37580/2) for an example of generating a java file and adding it to sources to be compiled.